# How to dynamically populate a list on an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

Before asking this question, I explored the existing answers for how to dynamically add elements to a list, and incorporated several of them into my attempt at a solution that meets my needs. However, it seems that the list is never being populated. I'm thinking the problem may be related to accessing the list to append the elements to, but I am not entirely sure.

My HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="row">
<div class="col-sm-4" id="faculty">
    <h3> Faculty Decks </h3>
    <ul id="faculty_list"> </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <h3> Instructions </h3>
    <p> Select your decks, select front (questions) or back (answers) of the the card and start studying. </p>
<div>
    <input class="front" type="radio" name="card" id="front" value="Front"> Front &ensp;</input>
    <input class="back" type="radio" name="card" id="back" value="Back"> Back</input>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button> Start Studying </button>
</div> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" id="student">
    <h3> Student Decks </h3>
    <ul id="student_list"> </ul>
</div>
```

I am calling the Javascript function else where in the HTML file, and I have confirmed that the function is called, the argument is what I expect, and the loop runs the appropriate number of times.

This is my Javascript function:

```
function populateLists(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
        //Create a new list element
        var list_item = document.createElement('li');   
        list_item.setAttribute('name', json[i].name);

        //Create the checkbox to add to the list element
        var select_checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        select_checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
        select_checkbox.id = json[i].deck_ID;

        //Add the checkbox to the list element
        list_item.appendChild(select_checkbox);

        var list = document.getElementById('row').getElementById((json[i].faculty=='1')?'faculty':'student' + '_list');

        list.append(list_item);
    }
 }
```

Comment: can you create a plunker example to demonstrate this? It looks like your html is missing some closing div tags. I cant see, where div with the id "row" is closing. Also, not particularly clear, if you really want add newly created 'li' element to div or to some ul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go!

```js
var json={'a': 'First', 'b': 'Second', 'c': 'Third'};
function makeUL(json) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(json).length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Object.values(json)[i]));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;
}

// Add the contents of json to #foo:
document.getElementById('foo').appendChild(makeUL(json));
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: This solution worked the best with the names of the decks!

Comment: Yes, but looping through the Object.keys is not needed! You could simply use the `for in` or `for of` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it wasn't finding the proper list.  I was getting the error that you can't chain getElementById calls, so I used queryselector instead.  I also broke out the  list name for readability.

```js
function populateLists(json) {
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
    //Create a new list element
    var list_item = document.createElement('li');   
    list_item.setAttribute('name', json[i].name);
    

    //Create the checkbox to add to the list element
    var select_checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    select_checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    select_checkbox.id = json[i].deck_ID;

    //Add the checkbox to the list element
    list_item.appendChild(select_checkbox);
    

    var list_name = (json[i].faculty=='1')?'faculty':'student' + '_list';
    var list = document.querySelector('#row #' + list_name);

    list.append(list_item);
}
}

var data = [{"name": "abcd", "deck_ID": "a123","faculty":'1'},{"name": "bcde", "deck_ID": "a123","faculty":'1'},{"name": "cdef", "deck_ID": "a123","faculty":'1'}];
populateLists(data);
```

```html
<div class="row" id="row">
<div class="col-sm-4" id="faculty">
    <h3> Faculty Decks </h3>
    <ul id="faculty_list"> </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <h3> Instructions </h3>
    <p> Select your decks, select front (questions) or back (answers) of the the card and start studying. </p>
<div>
    <input class="front" type="radio" name="card" id="front" value="Front"> Front &ensp;</input>
    <input class="back" type="radio" name="card" id="back" value="Back"> Back</input>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button> Start Studying </button>
</div> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" id="student">
    <h3> Student Decks </h3>
    <ul id="student_list"> </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way without the `Object.keys`:

```js
var dataObj ={'a': 'First', 'b': 'Second', 'c': 'Third'};
function createUL(json) {
    /* Create the list element: */
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for (var key in dataObj) {
        /* Create the list item: */
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        /* Set its contents: */
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dataObj[key]));

        /* Add it to the list: */
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    /* Return the constructed list: */
    return list;
}

/* Add the contents of dataObj to #bar: */
document.getElementById('bar').appendChild(createUL(dataObj));
```

```html
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example, though I'm guessing you'll want to add some text to the check boxes (easily done with a `<label>` tag).  I made up a JSON object to use as an example; to use this code just remove that object and pass your JSON object into `populateLists()`.

Some changes I made:

- Removed the chained `.getElementById` calls
- Changed `.append()` to `.appendChild()`
- Added the `onclick` attribute to the `Start Studying` button
- Added a missing `</div>` tag

```js
var json = [
  {name: "Person1",
  deck_ID: "Deck1",
  faculty: "1"
  },
  {name: "Person2",
  deck_ID: "Deck2",
  faculty: "1"
  },
  {name: "Person3",
  deck_ID: "Deck3",
  faculty: "1"
  }
];

function populateLists() {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
        //Create a new list element
        var list_item = document.createElement('li');   
        list_item.setAttribute('name', json[i].name);

        //Create the checkbox to add to the list element
        var select_checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        select_checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
        select_checkbox.id = json[i].deck_ID;

        //Add the checkbox to the list element
        list_item.appendChild(select_checkbox);

        var list = document.getElementById((json[i].faculty=='1')?'faculty':'student' + '_list');

        list.appendChild(list_item);
    }
 }
```

```html
<div class="row" id="row">
<div class="col-sm-4" id="faculty">
    <h3> Faculty Decks </h3>
    <ul id="faculty_list"> </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <h3> Instructions </h3>
    <p> Select your decks, select front (questions) or back (answers) of the the card and start studying. </p>
<div>
    <input class="front" type="radio" name="card" id="front" value="Front"> Front &ensp;</input>
    <input class="back" type="radio" name="card" id="back" value="Back"> Back</input>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button onclick="populateLists();"> Start Studying </button>
</div> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" id="student">
    <h3> Student Decks </h3>
    <ul id="student_list"> </ul>
</div>
</div>
```